# How to give cmd automated input via python

Tags: python, apktool, automated-deploy

I want to give cmd automated input command here is my code

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = subprocess.call("cmd",shell=True)
p = Popen('cmd', stdin=PIPE)    # NOTE: no shell=True here
p.communicate(os.linesep.join(["apktool d aalpha.apk"]))
```

This opens `cmd` for me in the project directory i.e `E:\myproject`.  Now I have this apktool in my project directory I am trying to run it automatically providing it the apktool run command in a way that I just open my python file and it executes the apktool.

Comment: Why won't you run the *apktool* directly?

Comment: i am working on a framework to automate this apktool. 
i just want to know how do i parse my input from script to cmd

Comment: What input? Why won't you run the apktool directly?

Comment: You're making this way more complex than it needs to be. In the subprocess call you're running the cmd inside a shell (shell=True) so you have a shell running inside a shell. Why? Then you're overwriting the contents of p (the results of the subprocess call) with the results of a Popen command, so the subprocess is being thrown away. pacholik is correct, just run apktool with the command arguments you want directly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
import subprocess;

commandA = 'start <path\file.png>';
p = subprocess.Popen(commandA, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT);
```

Comment: i want to automate input thats it 
i dont knw how. can u please provide ? that i run application and it gives it input itslef?